# Broadcast Receiver firing too often

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, receiver

I am having an issue where my application is constantly entering the onReceive method and I am not sure why. I entered some log statements but I still do not understand why the onReceive is being called. I did some research looking around, just trying to find examples of using BroadcastReceiver and AlarmManager, and I followed [this](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled) sample project, and found many other posts about users not being able to receive broadcasts, but none about users receiving too many.

Here is some of my code:

AlarmClock.java:

```
public class AlarmClock extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        Log.d("TAG", "Signal Recieved");
        SetAlarm(context);

        wl.release();
    }

    public void SetAlarm(Context context){
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent i = new Intent(context, AlarmService.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, i, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 32000, pi);

        Log.d("TAG", "Alarm Set");
    }
}
```

AlarmService.java:

```
public class AlarmService extends IntentService {

    public AlarmService(){
        super("AlarmService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TAG", "onHandleIntent");
        //operation to be completed
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.allen.repeatdialer" >

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    ...

    <receiver android:name=".AlarmClock">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.allen.repeatdials.CALL_PLACED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".AlarmService"></service>

</application>

...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

</manifest>
```

The application will only display Log.d("TAG", "onHandleIntent"); when I call sendBroadcast(), but the other log statements are displayed every 32 seconds. But also, after I call sendBroadcast() once, Log.d("TAG", "onHandleIntent"); will also be displayed every 32 seconds.

EDIT(Code that calls sendBroadcast()):

```
public class HomeScreen extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

//*******************************************************
//*                     On Create                       *
//*******************************************************
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
}

...

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0){
    switch (arg0.getId()){

        case R.id.bContact:
           displayContacts(Names, IDs);
           Log.d("TAG", "Contacts Pressed");
           break;

        case R.id.bStartDial:
            Log.d("TAG", "Dial Pressed");
            startDial();
            break;

        default:
            break;

    }
}


/* This method is responsible for placing the phone call.   */
public void startDial(){

    //performs call
    if (!phoneNumber.equals("")) {
        Uri number = Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber);
        Intent dial = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, number);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmClock.class);
        intent.setAction("com.example.allen.repeatdialer.CALL_PLACED");
        sendBroadcast(intent);

        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        startActivityForResult(dial, DIAL_COMMENCED);
    }
}   
}
```

Just to add some background information about this app, I had it working just fine using a handler, but the handler doesn't work if the CPU sleeps, so I am not trying to alter the application to use AlarmManager. So I know my issue lies within sending the broadcasts and receiving them.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls sendBroadcast()?

Comment: Try using LocalbroadcastManager.sendBroadcast();

Comment: Also, I don't think you want to put a class in with `Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmClock.class);`  The AlarmClock class is already registered, so you only need to set the action.  Checkout section 7.2 of this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html